# some button works, some buttons don't even though in same hierarchy

Tags: swift

Since I put content view in scrollview,

all buttons and other elements are under the hierarchy of contents view.

but some buttons works, some buttons not working, despite those are under

same hierarchy.

view -> scrollView -> contents view -> buttons(some can be tapped, some are not.) labels, imageView

I understood that buttons are hided by contents view, I tried put one button which didn't work before, under scrollview(which means same hierarchy as content view), it works.

**my questions are**

why some buttons are working even though those are in same hierarchy as other buttons?

how can I put button above the content view?
I use storyboard, if I do it, it will automatically goes in contents view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this same problem before -- buttons which are children of a child view with parent `ScrollView` do not respond to clicks even though they seemingly should based on the hierarchy. And honestly, **I never figured out why**, but adding buttons directly to `ScrollView` satisfied the task I needed to perform so there really was no need for a `contentView` anyway. If anyone knows why the buttons aren't clickable then I would be interested to hear it, but foregoing the content view is a valid option as long as there is no significant reason to have one.

If you want to add a new button to a `ScrollView` which has a `contentView` child, then just drag the `Button` over to the hierarchy on the left side of the Interface Builder and drop it on the `ScrollView`. It will then lay underneath the `ScrollView`, but in line with the child `contentView`. If you drop the `Button` in the visual layout, there will be no way to control where it falls in the hierarchy.

Comment: I did it without content view, but there is an ambiguous scrollabe content size warning.  this is why I put content view.

Comment: @JanghyupLee Okay gotcha, I understand. Honestly I just ignore that warning because I know that I handle it in the class file.